# Burninate MMORPG tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [mmorpg](/questions/tagged/mmorpg) tag should never see the light of day on Stack Overflow again.

Most of the few questions associated with this tags are either closed or asked by new users that don't understand the topics here.

If the question is programming related, there are a lot of more relevant tags a user can use. If it **requires** the information [mmorpg](/questions/tagged/mmorpg) it **is** off topic and should be migrated to [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) .

[image: BURNING UNICORN OF DEATH!]

Comment: +1 for the pic.  Now I have even more reason to fear BoltClock

Comment: I'm surprised that so many of those questions are still open.  Just kidding, I'm not.  But they won't be open in a minute...

Comment: We can't migrate questions older than 60 days.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Can't you simply delete them ?

Comment: We could, but we have credo to not unilaterally delete **good** content. That having been said, if the community deletes it, that's a whole 'nother issue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker How could the comunnity *delete* it ? By closing it ?

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd I think George means 20K community members exercising their delete privledge

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't that image in source called `burning_unicorn_of_death.jpg`???

Comment: @ryan I deserve a downvote for this. You can change it before someone else notice...

Comment: Is that Anna Lear's cat riding that unicorn?

Comment: The implication that it's *off topic* for Stack Overflow is incorrect.  It's true that Game Development has a more specific scope, but that doesn't mean it's off topic.  Questions regarding programming in the field of game development are most definitely *on* topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @casperOne ". Questions regarding programming in the field of game development are most definitely on topic for Stack Overflow." you're right about this.But my point here is that if I have a *programming* problem with a video game, my tags should be something like : `C#, XNA 4.0, VideoGames`. Adding the fact that the game is a `MMORPG` will not bring anything relevant to the post *on Stack Overflow*. Questions about video games programming should be asked here yes, but they should be tagged properly.

Comment: An impressive picture! I've spent my mana points to cast close spells for your cause!

Comment: @ŁukaszLech It should be automaticly added to the body of Burninate-Requests

Comment: I didn't even read the post before up-voting; the picture did it for me. Turns out the content merited an up-vote, too!

Comment: Successful burnination.

Comment: Excuse me, why does a Nazi-Unicorn now burn our tags?

Comment: I put on my robe and wizard hat and cast a level 21 spell of protection.